# build-essential set to manually installed (Debian 11)

Tags: apt

I installed `build-essential` by running `sudo apt install build-essential`. It was already installed and got the message:

build-essential set to manually installed

When running this command the second time this message disappeared (which makes sense).

What i do not understand: afaik all packages are always installed by using apt. Where does the message "build-essential set to manually installed" come from? When is a package flagged as manually installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package was installed automatically as a dependency for another package. If you remove the other package, build-essentials would have stayed until you run for example `apt autoremove`, which removes all packages that are not needed anymore.

Now, because it is set to manually, it would not be removed because it is not just a dependency anymore, it's a package you wanted directly.